# How to set a thumbnail to my custom file for a preview in Windows Explorer?

Tags: qt, file, thumbnails, preview, qfile

In my Qt application, I can save project files of my own type. I would like those files to have a nice preview in Windows explorer, just like picture and video files do by default. Is there a way to do that? I am using Qt, but maybe there is another way.

In other words, if my code for saving a file is as follows, I would like to know what to do in line 5 to make it work:

```
void saveFile(const QString& fileName, const QImage& thumbnail) {
    QFile file(fileName);
    file.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
    writeInFile(file); // Custom function that saves the project
    //file.setPreview(thumbnail); <- What I wish I could simply do
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can specify thumbnails for individual files. I believe they are handled based on the file extension. I am not sure if Windows explorer knows how to get thumbnails for specific file types for if there is some registry entry that tells it how to get one.

Answer (score 0):

Setting thumbnail for your own file type is not a Qt thing. It's job of Windows shell, and the behavior is controlled using registery.

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-to-a-file-type) if you want to assign a custom icon file.

If you want to generate different preview for each file, just like image file, then check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/cc144114(v=vs.85)).

Note they are Windows specific.